# how to center title text for WKInterfaceButton with iOS WatchKit

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacebutton

I tried this:

```
[myWKButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

I get the error:

> property titlelabel not found on object of type wkinterfacebutton

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WKInterfaceButton class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceButton/setAttributedTitle:) has no `titleLabel` property, which is the reason you are getting this error. To set the alignment of the title, use its `attributedTitle` property.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourTitle attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle}];
[myWKButton setAttributedTitle:attributedString];
```